# Laravel paginate belongsToMany relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pagination

I would like to paginate my results I get from my relationship. I have a products table/controller, a users table/controller and a markedProducts table. However, I don't have a markedProducts table because I don't actually need it. I use this solution to get all marked products of one user in my user model:

```
public function markedProducts(){    
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'products_marks');
}
```

My question now is how can I paginate my results **and** my second question is how can I get the `created_at` value of each row in my markedProducts table?

Because my solution is only returning the marked products. However, I would like to show the user when he has marked the product.

So far I had this idea:

```
$markedProducts = DB::table('products_marks')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(2);
$products = Product::whereIn('id', $markedProducts->lists('product_id'));
```

However, `->lists()` is not a method anymore and I actually don't want to bypass the Laravel methods and I don't want to loop through my pagination to get an array with all `product_id`'s.

Do you guys have any good and performant solution?

Kind regards and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Auth::user()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user) will return the authenticated user.

And use relationship method `markedProducts()` to get the query of products.

And then `orderBy` the column `created_at` of pivot table.

At last, apply paginate to this eloquent builder.

```php
Auth::user()->markedProducts()->orderBy('products_marks.created_at', 'DESC')->paginate($limit);
```